# Navigation Bar and Arrow does not align with each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my page, there is an arrow icon which points to the right and I want this to be aligned with my navigation active menu. My navigation menu is in a vertical manner. I will post here some code snippets. I don't know how to align since assigning its position won't work for me. Can someone please help me?

```css
.side-nav-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: unset;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.side-nav-bar a {
  padding: 18px 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818181;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: #e8e8e8;
  font-family: Malgun Gothic;
}

.side-nav-bar a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #293c4e;
}

a.active-menu {
  background-color: #293c4e;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class = "side-nav-bar content">
  <a class = "active-menu" href="#체육학">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
  <a href="#전공소개">전공소개</a>
  <a href="#졸업 후 진로">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="#졸업 후 진로">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="#교수소개">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I would be a great help if you post working fiddle here.

Comment: @Alex Deneris do you want the arrow align with the first row?

Answer (score 0):

Place the i tag inside the anchor tag, it will work

```
<div class = "side-nav-bar content">
    <a class = "active-menu" href="#체육학">체육학<i class="arrow right"></i></a>
    <a href="#전공소개">전공소개</a>
    <a href="#졸업 후 진로">졸업 후 진로</a>
    <a href="#졸업 후 진로">교육 프로그램</a>
    <a href="#교수소개">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**option 1: use css**

Use `position: absolute;top: 23px;right: 10px;` to `arrow` and `position:relative` to `.side-nav-bar`

```css
          .side-nav-bar {
               height: 100%;
              width: 200px;
               position: relative;
               z-index: 1;
                     top: 0;
               left: 0;
               background-color: #ffffff;
               overflow-x: hidden;
            }

          .side-nav-bar a  {
              padding: 18px 8px 16px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 15px;
              color: #818181;
              display: inline-block;
              border: none;
              background: none;
               width: 100%;
              text-align: left;
              outline: none;
              border-bottom-width: 1px;
              border-bottom-style: solid;
              border-color: #e8e8e8;
              font-family: Malgun Gothic;
           }

            .side-nav-bar a:hover {
               color: #ffffff;
             background-color: #293c4e;
            }

             a.active-menu {
                 background-color: #293c4e;
                color: #ffffff;
             }
                 .arrow {
      border: solid black;
      border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3px;
position: absolute;
top: 23px;
right: 10px;
    }

    .right {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class = "side-nav-bar content">
     <a class = "active-menu" href="#체육학">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
     <a href="#전공소개">전공소개</a>
     <a href="#졸업 후 진로">졸업 후 진로</a>
     <a href="#졸업 후 진로">교육 프로그램</a>
     <a href="#교수소개">교수소개</a>
    </div>
```

**Option 2:change html**

Insert `i` inside first  `a`

```css
             .side-nav-bar {
                   height: 100%;
                  width: 200px;
                   position: relative;
                   z-index: 1;
                         top: 0;
                   left: 0;
                   background-color: #ffffff;
                   overflow-x: hidden;
                }

              .side-nav-bar a  {
                  padding: 18px 8px 16px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  font-size: 15px;
                  color: #818181;
                  display: inline-block;
                  border: none;
                  background: none;
                   width: 100%;
                  text-align: left;
                  outline: none;
                  border-bottom-width: 1px;
                  border-bottom-style: solid;
                  border-color: #e8e8e8;
                  font-family: Malgun Gothic;
               }

                .side-nav-bar a:hover {
                   color: #ffffff;
                 background-color: #293c4e;
                }

                 a.active-menu {
                     background-color: #293c4e;
                    color: #ffffff;
                 }
                     .arrow {
          border: solid black;
          border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 3px;
        }

        .right {
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
```

```html
    <div class = "side-nav-bar content">
         <a class = "active-menu" href="#체육학">체육학 <i class="arrow right"></i></a>
         <a href="#전공소개">전공소개</a>
         <a href="#졸업 후 진로">졸업 후 진로</a>
         <a href="#졸업 후 진로">교육 프로그램</a>
         <a href="#교수소개">교수소개</a>
        </div>
```

**화이팅!!**

Comment: that what do you mean?